# constant eclipse crashes

Tags: eclipse

I am using the latest eclipse version (Indigo) on a machine: CPU: Intel Core i5 2.4 GHz, 8 GB RAM, 64-bit Windows, and eclipse keeps freezing very frequently. I increased all the memory things (permgen ...), but it did not help. When it stops responding a window pops out with the following data:

```
Java was started but returned exit code= -805306369
-XX:PermSize=256M
-XX:MaxPermSize = 512M
-Xms512m
-Xmx1024m
...
```

If you need more input, please feel free to ask :)

Any help would be very appreciated. Thank you, in advance.

Comment: did you try starting eclipse with a -clean argument after the changes?

Comment: For details of -clean   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430295/what-does-the-clean-parameter-mean-in-the-eclipse-ide/3430308#3430308

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at your 64 bit Windows; I remembered this thread. See if the solution there resolves it

https://superuser.com/questions/314015/eclipse-crashed

Also as my comments above suggests; a -clean start to eclipse is a good idea, as you have good enough RAM to get it cleaned faster. Slower machines will struggle cleaning every time you start eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

Run eclipse with -clearPersistedState from terminal/command prompt