# What does the eclipse command-line argument "-clean" exactly does?

Tags: eclipse

What does the eclipse command-line argument "-clean" exactly does?

I am using eclipse kepler.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430295/what-does-the-clean-parameter-mean-in-the-eclipse-ide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command line arguments of eclipse are actually rather well documented:
http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fmisc%2Fruntime-options.html&anchor=osgiclean

Since '-clean' will do the same as 'osgi.clean' set to 'true', here's what the doc says:

> if set to "true", any cached data used by the OSGi framework and eclipse runtime will be wiped clean. This will clean the caches used to store bundle dependency resolution and eclipse extension registry data. Using this option will force eclipse to reinitialize these caches.