# Eclipse IDE fails to start up after an update

Tags: eclipse

I can't run Eclipse after updating. It sends me a message that an error has occurred.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Workbench has not been created yet.
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.getWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.addons.SaveAllDirtyPartsAddon.getWorkbenchDisplay(SaveAllDirtyPartsAddon.java:261)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.addons.SaveAllDirtyPartsAddon.shutdown(SaveAllDirtyPartsAddon.java:213)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:55)
```

Log-file is attached: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1t5Y6PE06EIpNZYsM9S5ykZU5cB1CYFz7

Comment: Instead of a link, can you edit your question and add the log file?

Comment: sorry, could you help me, how I can add my log-file here???

Comment: You can copy and paste the relevant parts, indenting 4 spaces. https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code

Comment: the file is too big to attach it like that

Comment: You could share the relevant parts of it. Often it's helpful to just see the last few lines around the error itself.

Comment: the problem is I don't know what part of the file is relevant)))

Comment: go to your workspace, and remove `.metadata`, or better rename it to something like `.metadata_`. That will reset your eclipse's settings.

Comment: I removed .metadata but it didn't help

Answer (score 0):

There is a known open issue with Eclipse with **org.eclipse.launchbar.core**, and from content of your log file it looks that is also your problem. (Presumably you are using C/C++?)

See open [Eclipse Bug 509263](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=509263).

You could try to start Eclipse [using the -clean parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430295/what-does-the-clean-parameter-mean-in-the-eclipse-ide). I doubt if that will help, but it is a simple thing to try. Otherwise I think you will have to wait for the bug fix unless you see any helpful comments from posters in the bug entries.

It would also be helpful to update that Eclipse bug report with details of your specific problem if you still have not resolved the issue.