# After changing compiler settings in Eclipse, every class in my project suddenly fails to be resolved every time I save a file

Tags: java, eclipse, compiler-errors, eclipse-2019-03

I started having this problem yesterday. I changed some settings in Eclipse related to compiler warnings (changed some settings related to generic types from ignore to warning), and afterwards, every time I save a file, a bunch of compiler errors appear in places where there were none before, and the only thing that fixes it is **Project -> Clean**.

The compiler errors are related to:

> - "XmlBaseView cannot be resolved to a type"
> - "CHOICE_YESNO_NO cannot be resolved to a variable"
> - "the import client.rest.views.base.XmlBaseView cannot be resolved"
> - "The method XmlBaseView.getUrn() is undefined for the type XmlBaseView".

I literally add 1 character to a string variable and I get 126 errors in the Java file I edited as well as any other files related to it. I tried changing the settings I changed back to the original values, but it didn't help. I already tried restarting eclipse and rebooting, neither helped.

How do I fix this? I'm using Eclipse 2019-03 (4.11.0).

Comment: Are you using Gradle or Maven ?

Comment: @MichaelLaffargue No, just the default build/compile in Eclipse. Maybe Ant, but that's configured as an external tool, not my build tool or build script.

Comment: You could check: Project settings > Java build path > Source, ensure you have your source folder in it. Else usually the easy way is to create a new workspace and import your project inside. Resolve most of the configuration problems.

Comment: @MichaelLaffargue I'll keep that in mind in case no one comes up with a better solution.

Comment: Can you give a complete example of one of your error messages? The full message.

Comment: A simple option to try is restarting Eclipse using the **-clean** parameter. This old SO question provides more information, and is still relevant: [What does the -clean parameter mean in the Eclipse IDE?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3430295/2985643). Using **-clean** can't hurt, and it might help.